# Does the Twilio character limit apply to all channels?

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I'm building a bot using Twilio's autopilot and some responses will have messages exceeding 1500 characters. I have seen the error in my debugger view:

```
The concatenated message body exceeds the 1600 character limit.
```

But from [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21617#the-concatenated-message-body-exceeds-the-1600-character-limit) I could find on the error, there wasn't much to read.

Does this limit apply to all channels? i.e. Facebook Messenger, SMS, WhatsApp etc?

Any information will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a SMS character count limit.

[Maximum Message Length with Twilio Programmable Messaging](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360033806753-Maximum-Message-Length-with-Twilio-Programmable-Messaging)

WhatsApp and Facebook messenger are built on the same /Messages resource, to allow customers to use the same API easily across channels (whatsapp: and messenger:). Since this the case, they also have similar limits.

Comment: The article cleared it up. I don't know why I never came accross it. Thank you. But I was expecting different limits per channel though, it'd be much better because I don't plan on using SMSes. But it the developer set it so :)